# How to know the cause of failure?

Tags: java, android, performance, exception, error-handling

How can I find out if the app crashed in response to some user input or due to some internal error?

And how can I determine the best way to handle those exceptions from the users point of view?

Comment: try to use System.out.println("put values here");
Check value at every step where you think error may occur and the check the log cat for results you will get the results

Comment: Log cat is good way to identify errors and after you found bug use try catch so next time your application not going to crash.

Comment: @Codelord is their anyway to know that application is forcefully stopped by the os??

Comment: @SumeetRathore I didnt get your question.

Comment: if i am a user and app crashes. How come user will know that is caused by him or it due to some code fault

Comment: @Codelord i mean is their any system method or any line of code which i need to write to know whether the application is stopped by system.??

Comment: Actually Its an interview question so need some theoretical approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we definitely talking Java? There pretty much everything will throw on error from accessing an array out of bounds to overflowing a buffer.

The exceptions thrown here are in a class called `unchecked exceptions` and they're not necessarily even meant to be caught since they're the result of programmer error (bug), not user input error.

So that's one way to tell if it's an input error or not. If the exception thrown is an unchecked exception, then the bug is in the code. You can have a sanity catch for unchecked exceptions at the entry point of your software to just try to determine what happened as a last resort, possibly dumping a stack trace to help users report bugs.

If the crash didn't even throw (ex: segfault), then it occurred in native code rather than Java code, and is still not the user's fault (though it could be the fault of a third party library you're using rather than your own, e.g., though it would be the developer's responsibility to do something about it).

If it's a user input error which you handle, then you want to throw a checked error and catch it. The user won't even see a crash in that case.

From a user point of view, any uncaught exception is a programmer error. If the software doesn't gracefully recover from any kind of exception, input-based or not, then technically the liability is with the developers. It's not my fault if a software crashes because I accidentally typed in a negative number into a field that wanted positive numbers. Even trying to load a corrupt file shouldn't necessarily crash a software, so perhaps your interviewer was looking for the kind of answer of a responsible developer who never sees any crash as being the user's fault.

When we're talking crashes, it's not in the domain of user input vs. bug. It's always a bug in a production-quality commercial software.

If it's in the domain of code, then there are different classes of checked exceptions based on exceptional but not unanticipated user input errors (ex: file I/O error) as opposed to just completely unanticipated bugs (unchecked exceptions) which you can distinguish when you're in control of the code and handling exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code into try-catch block. This will allow you to catch exceptions (errors) and then write stack trace into the console. From the stack trace in the console you will be able to find the line of a bug in your code....

```
try {
    your code here
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```